# How to measure time for maze generation?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

How can I insert a timer to my code? My goal is to know how long it would take for my maze to generate because I am comparing it to the previous program for my thesis.

Thanks for the big help. :)

Here is the code that I used:

```
public class Maze extends JPanel {

private Room[][] rooms;// m x n matrix of rooms
private ArrayList<Wall> walls; // List of walls
private Random rand;// for random wall
private int height;// height of matrix
private int width;// width of matrix
private int num;// incrementor
private JoinRoom ds;// union paths

// paint methods //
private int x_cord; // x-axis rep
private int y_cord;// y-axis rep
private int roomSize;
private int randomWall;

public Maze(int height, int width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    rooms = new Room[height][width];
    walls = new ArrayList<Wall>((height - 1) * (width - 1));
    generateRandomMaze();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 700));
 }
private void generateRandomMaze() {
    generateInitialRooms();// see next method
    ds = new JoinRoom(width * height);
    rand = new Random(); // here is the random room generator
    num = width * height;

    while (num > 1) {
       // when we pick a random wall we want to avoid the borders getting eliminated
        randomWall = rand.nextInt(walls.size());
        Wall temp = walls.get(randomWall);
        // we will pick two rooms randomly 
        int roomA = temp.currentRoom.y + temp.currentRoom.x * width;
        int roomB = temp.nextRoom.y + temp.nextRoom.x * width;

        // check roomA and roomB to see if they are already members 
        if (ds.find(roomA) != ds.find(roomB)) {
            walls.remove(randomWall);
            ds.unionRooms(ds.find(roomA), ds.find(roomB));
            temp.isGone = true;
            temp.currentRoom.adj.add(temp.nextRoom);
            temp.nextRoom.adj.add(temp.currentRoom);
            num--;
        }// end of if
    }// end of while
}

 // name the room to display
private int roomNumber = 0;
/**
 * Sets the grid of rooms to be initially boxes
 * This is self explanitory, we are only creating an reverse L for all
 * The rooms and there is an L for the border
 */
private void generateInitialRooms() {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            // create north walls
            rooms[i][j] = new Room(i, j);
            if (i == 0) {
                rooms[i][j].north = new Wall(rooms[i][j]);
            } else {
                rooms[i][j].north = new Wall(rooms[i - 1][j], rooms[i][j]);
                walls.add(rooms[i][j].north);
            }
            if (i == height - 1) {
                rooms[i][j].south = new Wall(rooms[i][j]);
            }
            if (j == 0) {
                rooms[i][j].west = new Wall(rooms[i][j]);
            } else {
                rooms[i][j].west = new Wall(rooms[i][j - 1], rooms[i][j]);
                walls.add(rooms[i][j].west);
            }
            if (j == width - 1) {
                rooms[i][j].east = new Wall(rooms[i][j]);
            }
            rooms[i][j].roomName = roomNumber++;// we will name the rooms
        }
    }
    // initalize entrance and exit
    rooms[0][0].west.isGone = true;// you can replace .west.isGone with .north.isGone
    // this is just saying the roomName for top left is 0 
    rooms[0][0].roomName = 0;
    // we will remove the south wall of the last room
    rooms[height - 1][width - 1].south.isGone = true;
    // this is just saying the roomName for bottom right is the last element in the mxn room matrix
    rooms[height - 1][width - 1].roomName = (height * width);
}

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    x_cord = 40;
    y_cord = 40;
    // could have taken height as well as width
    // just need something to base the roomsize
    roomSize = (width - x_cord) / width + 7;

    // temp variables used for painting
    int x = x_cord;
    int y = y_cord;

    for (int i = 0; i <= height - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= width - 1; j++) {
            if (!(rooms[i][j].north.isGone)) {
                g.drawLine(x, y, x + roomSize, y);
            }//end of north if
            // west wall not there draw the line
            if (rooms[i][j].west.isGone == false) {
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + roomSize);
            }// end of west if
            if ((i == height - 1) && rooms[i][j].south.isGone == false) {
                g.drawLine(x, y + roomSize, x + roomSize,
                        y + roomSize);
            }// end of south if
            if ((j == width - 1) && rooms[i][j].east.isGone == false) {
                g.drawLine(x + roomSize, y, x + roomSize,
                        y + roomSize);
            }// end of east if
            x += roomSize;// change the horizontal
        }// end of inner for loop
        x = x_cord;
        y += roomSize;
    }// end of outer for loop
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // we will use the scanner for userInput
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m, n;// these are variables for the size of maze (m x n)
    System.out.print("Enter the size of your maze: ");
    // store the input
    m = userInput.nextInt();
    n = userInput.nextInt(); 

    // use JFrame to put the created panel on 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 800);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Maze(m, n));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}// end of main
  }// END OF CLASS
```

Comment: Look at `System.currentTimeMillis()`!

Comment: Looking up the time functions in any Java documentation should be fairly trivial yet you've not said whether or not you attempted this and what problems you encountered. Surely if you could write this code, you could search for time functions?

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a Timer class to do this, you can find it here: https://github.com/twothe/newdawn/blob/master/two/newdawn/util/TimeCounter.java

It is very simple and sufficient for most tasks.

The general difficulty with Java is that code is not executed at a constant time. Somewhere in between the Garbage Collector might interrupt your timing, or the JIT considers a piece of code to slow and suddenly optimizes it. All these things will mess up any measurements done with `System.nanoTime()`, so don't take the numbers as facts, but more as a tendency.

If you want to have exact numbers, you need to use more sophisticated tools and especially run the code in question a thousand or billion times to rule out background noise, but even then those numbers are only valid for your local machine, and could be entirely different on a different hardware.

Answer (score -1):

It depends how you want the information. The easiest way is to use System.currentTimeInMillis() before you start generation, then again afterwards, and compare the results. That'll give you the number of ms taken to generate.

e.g.

```
walls = new ArrayList<Wall>((height - 1) * (width - 1));
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();    
generateRandomMaze();
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();    
System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (endTime-startTime) + "ms");
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 700));
```

Comment: There are several errors: 1) There is no method `currentTimeInMillis`. 2) Strings can't mathematically add a long number.

Comment: 1) I say current time in millis when I talk about it, and typed the same, oops! 2) I added the strings as an after-thought and missed the brackets. Thanks for the headsup.

Comment: p.s. 2 is not several :p

Comment: I thought, I'll find another one, but I didn't. In the end I forgot to change **several** to **two** :p  But in sum, there were 3 errors, right? ;)

Comment: That's not an error, that just means his code is quick. The other mistakes were coding errors. I did say it depends how he wanted the information. If he wants it to go to nano second precision he can change it. I provided a solution to his problem, that would most likely do what he needs it to do.